# Adding View Model to Resources Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am having a Silverlight Application.

I am adding resources and datacontext to Xaml.cs file in the constructor of class of the a XAML file as under :

```
//Constructor
public Class()
    {
        _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        this.Resources.Add("VM", _mainViewModel );
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _mainViewModel ;
    }
```

Everything works fine.

When I am adding the same resources and datacontext in the XAML file as under :

```
<controls:UserControlClient.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel" />
</controls:UserControlClient.Resources>
<controls:UserControlClient.DataContext >
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Name="mainViewModel"/>
</controls:UserControlClient.DataContext>
```

it causing a problem and all the lists and properties that are set are reinitailized agin.
why is it so??

Answer (score 1):

See  @Amandeep's answer. And also the way you assign DataContext in XAML doesn't make use of the ViewModel declared in Resources, that will instantiate another MainViewModel object. It should be :

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <controls:UserControlClient>
        <controls:UserControlClient.DataContext >
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="mainViewModel"/>
        </controls:UserControlClient.DataContext>
    </controls:UserControlClient>
</StackPanel>
```

or simply assign DataContext as property instead of element :

```
<controls:UserControlClient DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=mainViewModel}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources and data context must be given in xaml or cs .if you give these on both, it will reintialize control twice as in xaml when you define datacontext or resources it will again call 'Initializecomponent' method.